# Cassandra disk space overhead

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra-2.0

We are running a 6 node Cassandra 2.0.11 cluster with RF=3 at AWS in a single datacenter across 3 AZ's

Our average datasize is about 110GB and each node has 2 80GB disks with raid0 to create a single 160GB disk.

We are starting to see the disk fill up whenever a repair or subsequent compaction takes place and are no longer able to rebalance the ring.

Is it time to horizontally scale and move from 6 to 9 nodes?

It seems like 50GB out of 160GB is a lot of overhead required for "normal" cassandra operation.

Comment: I wanted to add that we are already using LCS and have checked that we do not have any snapshots.  One thing we've found that was helpful was to bump compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec from 16 MB/s to 32 MB/s.  The ring is quiet now that the compactions have finished and we have not run any more repair operations.  We've decided to try to scale from 6 to 9 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Get more disk space if you can. 
Otherwise consider using leveled compaction in case you're low on disk space and only have small to moderate write load. LCS can save significant disk space during compaction compared to size tired compaction.
Also check if you can delete some old snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the root cause of what is causing your disks to fill up.

From what you wrote, it sounds to me like the load on the cluster is too high which causes compaction to fall behind. This in turn would cause the disks to fill up.

Check nodetool tpstats to see whether there is a backlog of compactions and check how many sstables are in your Columnfamilies. If this is the case, either scale horizontally to handle the load or tune your current cluster so that it can handle the load that is being pushed.

The cause could also stem from a huge compaction that floods the data drive. I assume you use Size-tiered compaction strategy. The overhead for this is 50% of your current data at all times. As a big compaction can temporarily add that much data.

One option could be switching to Leveled Compaction Strategy as this only requires an overhead of 10%. Note however that LCS is much harder on the disks.